# Do I need a resistor for a 3v3 led?

Tags: gpio, electronics

Begginer question, if the output voltage of the raspberry pi is 3.3v and my led voltage is 3.3v, do I still need a resistor? As far as I understand, if the voltage is the same you don't need to add a resistor.

Comment: How much current will your LED consume at 3.3v ?

Comment: I think 20 mA..

Comment: What is a 3.3V LED? A resistor is needed to limit current- 16 mA is the maximum for GPIO

Comment: @Milliways: Actually, [there are hundreds of 3.3V LEDs](https://www2.mouser.com/Optoelectronics/LED-Lighting/LED-Emitters/Standard-LEDs-SMD/_/N-b1bb1?P=1yox9i5)

Answer (score 1):

A resistor is needed to limit the current flow.  If a resistor is integrated with the LED you're using, then you need not add one. But make sure you've got the specification correct; if you don't limit the current,  the LED will burn out as it will try to draw as much current as is provided.